# controller that used in interface of DAL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, web-applications, interface

i have class in the DAL that implement interface from the BL.
in the controller i call to the function in DAL by object of the interface- BL.
but, i try to add this line:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILocationRepository, LocationController>();
and is error:CS0311
please, help me!

Comment: Does `LocationController` implement the interface `ILocationRepository`?  Both the name and the error suggest that it doesn't.  (And it *probably* shouldn't.)  It's not really clear to me *why* you're trying to add that line of code or what you're expecting that to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in LocationController has an object from the type ILocationRepository  with dependecy-injection in the c'tor. the class LocationRepository in the DAL, without any references.

Comment: For the shown line to work LocationController needs to be a ILocationRepository. It must implement that interface not use something that implements that interface. There seems to be a major missunderstanding on how dependency injection works. So if you want help show more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment on the question:

> LocationController has an object from the type ILocationRepository with dependecy-injection in the c'tor. the class LocationRepository in the DAL

Then the service you want to inject is `LocationRepository`, not `LocationController`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILocationRepository, LocationRepository>();
```

On this line you're not telling the dependency injector what classes will need an instance of `ILocationRepository` (as you certainly wouldn't want to have to list *all possible places it's needed* here, not to mention that in your attempt you're telling the dependency injector *nothing* about where to find an implementation of `ILocationRepository`), but instead you're telling it what implementation to *provide* for `ILocationRepository` anywhere that it's needed.